# Compartir variables en multiprocessing python

Tags: python

tengo un problema con multiprocessing, estoy haciendo un programa que se conecta con dalle de openai, mediante un microfono le dices lo que quieres y este te lo muestra, el problema que tengo es que estoy usando multiprocessing en un nucleo estoy procesando la voz, lee un puerto serie que es un simple boton para escuchar, y de ahi lo manda a dalle, en el otro proceso estoy mostrando la imagenes que van saliendo, pero quiero enviar la variable "Cambio" al otro proceso de lectura de imagenes, he leido mucho blogs sobre esto pero ninguno me ha funcionado, espero me pueda ayudar con esto, dejo mi codigo:

```
import serial
import openai
import os
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
import webbrowser
import requests
import shutil
import cv2
import ctypes
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
ban = 0
cambio = 0
sr.Microphone()
r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 300
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = False
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
ancho, alto = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
dirname = 'C:/Users/alexis'

def convertir():
    global tiempo, ban
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        print("escuchando")
        recorded_audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        palabra = r.recognize_google(
            recorded_audio,
            language="es-MX"
        )
        ban = 1
        return palabra
    except Exception as ex:
        print("No se detecto voz")

def createImg(frase):
    global cambio
    """respuesta = openai.Image.create(
        prompt=frase,
        size='1024x1024',
        n=1
    )
    image_url = respuesta["data"][0]["url"]
    nombre_local_imagen = "fotos/imagen0.png" # El nombre con el que queremos guardarla
    imagen = requests.get(image_url).content
    with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(imagen)"""
    cambio = 1

class MySerialManager(Process):
    def __init__(self, serial_port, baudrate=9600, timeout=1):
        super(MySerialManager, self).__init__(target=self.loop_iterator,args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout))

    def loop_iterator(self,serial_port, baudrate,timeout):
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)
        self.loop(ser)

    def loop(self,ser):
        arduino = ser.readline()
        arduino = str(arduino)
        if arduino.find("entro") > 1:
            frase = convertir()
            print("Usted quizo decir: '", frase)
            if str(frase)!='None':
                createImg(frase) 
                

def conexion():
    msm = MySerialManager("COM3")
    try:
        msm.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("caught in main")
    finally:
        msm.join() 

def VariationImg():
    print("modificando")
    """imageRead = open('fotos/imagen0.png','rb')
    imMod = openai.Image.create_variation(
    image=imageRead,
    size='1024x1024',
    n=4)
    for n in range (4):
        nombre_local_imagen = "fotos/imagen"+str(n+1)+".png" # El nombre con el que queremos guardarla
        imagen = requests.get(imMod["data"][n]["url"]).content
        with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(imagen)"""

def ShowImg():
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(dirname) and os.path.isdir(dirname):
            if not os.listdir(dirname):
                time.sleep(2)
            else:  
                initial_count = 0
                for path in os.listdir(dirname):
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, path)):
                        initial_count += 1  
                if initial_count == 5:
                    Variation = multiprocessing.Process(target = VariationImg)
                    Variation.start()
                    for n in range(5):
                        imagen = cv2.imread("fotos/imagen"+str(n)+".png")        
                        res = cv2.resize(imagen, dsize=(ancho,alto),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                        cv2.namedWindow("hola", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
                        cv2.setWindowProperty("hola", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
                        cv2.imshow("hola",res)
                        cv2.waitKey(4000)
                        if n < 4:
                            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                else:
                    imageRead = open('fotos/imagen0.png','rb')
                    imMod = openai.Image.create_variation(
                        image=imageRead,
                        size='1024x1024',
                        n=4)
                    for n in range (4):
                        nombre_local_imagen = "fotos/imagen"+str(n+1)+".png" # El nombre con el que queremos guardarla
                        imagen = requests.get(imMod["data"][n]["url"]).content
                        with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
                            handler.write(imagen)
        else:
            os.mkdir(dirname) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        if ban==0:
            Show=multiprocessing.Process(target=ShowImg)
            Show.start()
            ban=1
        conexion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu variable es un entero lo mas simple es usar memoria compartida a través de `multiprocessing.Value`, recordando siempre hacer uso de un lock  si la operación no es atómica para evitar condiciones de carrera. `Value` proporciona un RLock por defecto, aunque puedes pesarle uno propio si lo necesitas a través del argumento `lock`:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value


def funcion(cambio):
    for _ in range(30):
        time.sleep(1)
        with cambio.get_lock():
            cambio.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cambio = Value('i', 0)
    proc = Process(target=funcion, args=(cambio,))
    
    proc.start()
    for _ in range(100):
        print(cambio.value)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Si compartieras la variable en una red entre varios dispositivos o necesitaras usar tipos mas complejos podrías recurrir a `multiprocessing.Manager`, pero para este caso `Value` y un `Lock` bastan.

> NOTA: Dado que `Value` usa [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), tipos compatibles con C, es
> importante que elijas el tipo adecuadamente en base a tus necesidades.
> Por ejemplo, en el caso de los enteros debes tener en cuenta el rango
> que cada tipo puede representar en base a si tiene o no signo y al
> numero de bytes que usa para evitar casos de *integer overflow*.

---

Ahora bien, me da la impresión que intentas usar la variable como una señal para que el otro proceso haga algo cuando se ha completado una tarea en el otro. Si es el caso, puedes usar `multiprocessing.Event`:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Event


def funcion(event):
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
        event.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = Event()
    proc = Process(target=funcion, args=(event,))
    proc.start()
    
    while True:
        # Hacer otras cosas
        if event.is_set():
            print(f"{time.time()}: Algo paso")
            event.clear()
        # Hacer otras cosas
```

Puedes usar `Event.wait` para bloquear la ejecución hasta que pase cierto tiempo o el evento se establezca:

```
    while True:
        event.wait(0.1)
        if event.is_set():
            print(f"{time.time()}: Algo paso")
            event.clear()
```

O esperar indefinidamente:

```
    while True:
        event.wait()
        print(f"{time.time()}: Algo paso")
        event.clear()
```

---

### Edición

Puedes pasar la instancia de `multiprocessing.Value` a cuantos subprocesos quieras. Por ejemplo, simplificando tu código para hacerlo fácilmente reproducible, puedes compartir el valor con el proceso que ejecuta `ShowImg` y con el que ejecuta `MySerialManager.loop_iterator`/`createImg` de la siguiente forma:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

ban = 0


def createImg(frase, cambio):
    with cambio.get_lock():
        cambio.value = random.randint(0, 1)

class MySerialManager(Process):
    def __init__(self, serial_port, cambio, baudrate=9600, timeout=1):
        super().__init__(
            target=self.loop_iterator,
            args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout, cambio)
            )

    def loop_iterator(self, serial_port, baudrate, timeout, cambio):
        ser = ""
        self.loop(ser, cambio)

    def loop(self, ser, cambio):
        frase = ""
        createImg(frase, cambio) 
                
def conexion(cambio):
    msm = MySerialManager("COM3", cambio)
    try:
        msm.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("caught in main")
    finally:
        msm.join() 

def ShowImg(cambio):
    while True:
        with cambio.get_lock():
            if cambio.value == 1:
                print("Cambio")
                cambio.value = 0
            else:
                print("Sin cambio")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cambio = Value("i", 0)
    while True:
        if ban == 0:
            show = Process(target=ShowImg, args=(cambio,))
            show.start()
            ban = 1
        conexion(cambio)
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono con lock, pero ahora esa variable ya me retornar de unos de mis procesos, pero como la puedo mandar al otro proceso que se esta ejecutando en parelalo, porque esa otra funcion que se llama ShowImg, la mando a llamar una sola vez en todo el programa pero dentro le puse un while para que se quede ejecutando todo el tiempo sin parar, y si la estoy llamando varias veces empieza el proceso de nuevo y se va acumulando las imagenes que muestra, por eso la deje en un bluce infinito y solo la llame una vez

Comment: Hola Alexis, he editado la respuesta para intentar mostrar como puedes compartir memoria entre los dos subprocesos. No se exactamente el uso que quieres darle a la variable en ShowImg y he simplificado mucho el código para que sea fácilmente reproducible, pero debería darte la idea básica de como puedes leer y modificar la variable compartida desde ambos subprocesos.